# Can someone tell me why this script doesn't run?

Tags: javascript

When I open this page nothing happen. So what is the error on this code?
This is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function code(){
        var filename = loc.pathname.split("/");
        filename = filename[pathname.length-1];
        alert(filename);
    <iframe src="http://url/" +currentPageUrl scrolling="yes" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
        Your browser doesn't support IFrames
        </iframe>`
        }

        </script>
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body onload="code();">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's `loc` defined?

Comment: You can't add iframe in the dom like that

Comment: There are so many things wrong with your code! I suggest you start by learning javascript syntax.

Comment: dont know what you are trying to do. I think i will forget coding seeing your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but there are lot of mistakes in your code.

`loc` should be location

just guessing that your trying something similar to this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function code() {
                var filename = location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                document.body.innerHTML = "<iframe src=" + filename + " scrolling='yes' style='position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;'>your browser doesn't support iframe<iframe>";
            }
        </script>
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="code();">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have a valid script there.

1. loc is undefined.
2. You just have an iFrame tag flying around in your JS code.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with this code:

1. `loc` looks like it's not defined. Maybe you want `location`
2. To add code to the DOM, you could use:

   `document.body.innerHTML = "<iframe src='http://' + variable ></iframe>"`
3. Make sure all other variables are defined. i.e. use `location.pathname` when getting the length.